# Django-Use two class based views in one template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have my two class based views, One for just showing some stuffs and other is a image upload form. Now In my template, I want to both show stuffs and the ability to upload images through one template.

```
#models.py
class Page(Group):
    name = models.IntegerField()

class Photo(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField()
```

In views.py, I have two views like this:

```
class UploadView(View):

    model = Photo 

    def get(self, request,*args, **kwargs):
        photos_list = Photo.objects.all()
        return render(self.request, 'page/upload.html', {'photos': photos_list})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = PhotoForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            photo = form.save()
            data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': photo.file.name, 'url': photo.file.url}
        else:
           data = {'is_valid': False}
        return JsonResponse(data)


class PageDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Page
    template_name = 'page/page_detail.html'
```

You can see I have two separate templates for two views.
Also, my photo upload form is like this:

```
class PhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('file', )
```

Now in my pagedetailview's template, I show stuffs like this:

```
{{ page.name }}
<!-- and various things -->
```

And in my upload.html, I have a button for uploading. When I click that button, it takes me to file explorer to choose photos that I want to upload. Kind of like this:

```
#upload photo's template
<div >
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-upload-photos">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span> Upload photos
  </button>
  <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="file" 
       data-url="{% url 'upload' %}"
       data-form-data='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
</div>
```

Basically this template allows me to press a button and upload some photos. I use jquery and some javascript for this. Okay, now back to question.

I do want to upload this photos in the 'page detail view' page. So here is like two views. What can I do so that I can access this two views into one template?

Any help will be much much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can just render combined template in your `UploadView`

Comment: I don't understand, can you please elaborate a bit? How to do so? Do I need to override get_queryset ? Also in upload view I basically defined what will happen for get and post request. Now, for get request how do I pass additional context?

Comment: There is a [great guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-formmixin-with-detailview) in Django docs that shows how to solve your exact problem in different ways